# Splitting up a long line of HTML into multiple lines

Tags: perl

I have some website (not my own) that have SUPER long lines where they have minified the HTML. Normally this isn't a problem, but its causing issues with some of my regexes (in this example I'm working on, there are 12 lines, and one of the lines if 750k characters long!!!!).

What I want to be able to do, is split the lines up into more manageable lines so it doesn't cause the regex engine to choke. I was thinking something like this:

```
$_[0] =~ s/([\w\d\W]{5000}[^\<])/$1\n/g;
```

It kind of works - but breaks it in places I don't want. Ideally I just want to break it up to 5000 chars long, thus more manageable lines. Or better yet, properly formatted. I'm using `HTML::TreeBuilder` in the code as well (before the regexes), so I tried to clean up the HTML with:

```
        my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($page);
        print $tree->as_HTML;
```

...but this gives it all on one line, so its useless for what I need. So my question:

- Is there a nice regex I could use that would split it into multiple lines? (I don't care about indenting, as its only to match regexes on)
- A way for HTMLL::TreeBuilder to export the DOM into a string on multiple lines?

Comment: Do you match content or actual HTML with your patterns? How are you going to make sure your patterns don't break if there are random newlines in the input string?

Comment: @simbabque thats kind of my problem :) They are quite clunky regexes to extract details from the website from the HTML itself: `(\<[biu]\>)?Company (?:number|num)(\<\/[biu]\>)?(\s+?|)\:?(\s+?|)([0-9]{7,8})`

Comment: Are there elements that you never use in your patterns but are common to the pages, like `<div>`?

Comment: Oh. HTML::TreeBuilder was last released by [the late Kent Fredric](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/lhx74s/rip_kent_frederic_kentnl/). :'(

Comment: @simbabque erm I guess `<br>`. Yes, very sad about him dying :(

Comment: So can you replace all `<br>`s with newlines?

Comment: @simbabque yeah I guess. What would you suggest as a quick way to see if any one line is over x chars? I don't want to do any more work on the other files that are ok (i.e not stupidly long). There are only a small number of them, but they cause the forks to hang

Comment: Run `length` on them, and if they're too long, do something like `s/(.{5000}.+?<br>)/$1\n/g` or similar. Basically at least 5k lines and then some more until the next `<br>` tag.

Comment: @simbabque cool - will give that a go. Sometimes the simplest ideas are the best! haha

Comment: You could `s/>/>\n/mg` maybe to break after each tag?

Comment: That's the hard part about programming. You see the simple code and think I can never come up with that, but you don't see how much work went in there in between to reach that state -- Want me to write it up as an answer?

Comment: yes please. TBH I've gone over thousands of lines of code today, so you end up missing the silly stuff. Sometimes you just need a 2nd pair of eyes to take a fresh look at it. I always end up overcomplicating stuff for the sake of it it seems ;)

Comment: Maybe better use [HTML::PrettyPrinter](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/CLMS/HTML-PrettyPrinter-0.03/PrettyPrinter.pm) ?

Comment: @emi thanks - not heard of that module before. Will check it out

Comment: Ha! If ever we are allowed to have another one, you should make an exception and drop in. I'm one of the organisers. London Perl Mongers now meets on Jitsi, still on the Thursday after the first Wednesday of the month. You're welcome to join us for a drink, too! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find an element in the HTML that is common, but is not part of your patterns, and break on that. In the comments you suggested `<br>`, so we will go with that.

If you only want to bother splitting lines up if they're over a certain length, check for that first. Then append `<br>` tags after a certain amount of chars with newlines.

```perl
if (length $html > 100_000) {
  my $segment_length = 20_000;
  $html =~ s{
    (
      .{$segment_length} # at least n chars
      .+?                # and some padding
      <br(?:\s/)?>       # and an (x)html br tag
    )
  }{$1\n}gx;
}
```